# Change in basis for a double projection vector using intrinsic Euler angles

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations, 3d, change-of-basis

I have a unit vector defined by double projection angles, with $\alpha$ being the angle towards the positive $y$-axis from the positive $x$-axis, and $\beta$ being the angle towards the positive $z$-axis from the $xy$-plane.

Now I want to offset the coordinate system (change of basis) using intrinsic $z-y^\prime-x^{\prime\prime}$ Euler angles ($\psi$, $\theta$, $\phi$), as shown below (note: the new $X$-axis is in green, but the new $Y$ and $Z$ axes are not shown):

[image]

If the original vector remains the same, how can it be described using projection angles $A$ and $B$, relative to the new $XYZ$ coordinate system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original vector defined as a matrix in $xyz$ by the projection angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$:

$${{\vec v}_{xyz}} = \left[ {\matrix{
   {\cos \beta \cos \alpha }  \cr 
   {\cos \beta \sin \alpha }  \cr 
   {\sin \beta }  \cr 
} } \right]$$

Rotation matrix for the change in basis using yaw, pitch, and roll angles:

$${R_{xyz \to XYZ}} = \left[ {\matrix{
   {\cos \psi \cos \theta } & {\cos \psi \sin \theta \sin \phi  - \sin \psi \cos \phi } & {\cos \psi \sin \theta \cos \phi  - \sin \psi \sin \phi }  \cr 
   {\sin \psi \cos \theta } & {\sin \psi \sin \theta \sin \phi  - \cos \psi \cos \phi } & {\sin \psi \sin \theta \cos \phi  - \cos \psi \sin \phi }  \cr 
   { - \sin \theta } & {\cos \theta \sin \phi } & {\cos \theta \cos \phi }  \cr 
} } \right]$$

Application of transformation:

$$\eqalign{
  & {{\vec V}_{XYZ}} = R\vec v =   \cr 
  & \left[ {\matrix{
   {\cos \psi \cos \theta \cos \beta \cos \alpha  + \cos \psi \sin \theta \sin \phi \cos \beta \sin \alpha  - \sin \psi \cos \phi \cos \beta \sin \alpha  + \cos \psi \sin \theta \cos \phi \sin \beta  - \sin \psi \sin \phi \sin \beta }  \cr 
   {\sin \psi \cos \theta \cos \beta \cos \alpha  + \sin \psi \sin \theta \sin \phi \cos \beta \sin \alpha  - \cos \psi \cos \phi \cos \beta \sin \alpha  + \sin \psi \sin \theta \cos \phi \sin \beta  - \cos \psi \sin \phi \sin \beta }  \cr 
   { - \sin \theta \cos \beta \cos \alpha  + \cos \theta \sin \phi \cos \beta \sin \alpha  + \cos \theta \cos \phi \sin \beta }  \cr 
 } } \right] \cr} $$

Extracting the new double projection angles $A$ and $B$:

$$\eqalign{
  & {{\vec V}_Z} = \sin B  \cr 
  & B = \arcsin \left( { - \sin \theta \cos \beta \cos \alpha  + \cos \theta \sin \phi \cos \beta \sin \alpha  + \cos \theta \cos \phi \sin \beta } \right)  \cr 
  & {{\vec V}_X} = \cos B\cos A  \cr 
  & A = \arccos \left( {{{\cos \psi \cos \theta \cos \beta \cos \alpha  + \cos \psi \sin \theta \sin \phi \cos \beta \sin \alpha  - \sin \psi \cos \phi \cos \beta \sin \alpha  + \cos \psi \sin \theta \cos \phi \sin \beta  - \sin \psi \sin \phi \sin \beta } \over {\cos B}}} \right) \cr} $$